# Подключение библиотеки в NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 11.2
Java: 13.0.1;
Создал новый проект Java-приложение на Maven. В папку проекта скопировал jar-файл. Добавил библиотеку через Tools/Libraries/Add JAR/Folder.  Классы библиотеки не видят друг друга - не работает переход к классу библиотеки при удержании Ctrl. При обращении к классу библиотеки через Class.forName вылетает ClassNotFoundException. Пробовал удалять, добавлять библиотеку заново, чистил кэш NetBeans Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Если у вас maven проект, то он должен работать через maven. Не нужно соединять ant с maven. Подключайте к проекту другой проект. Maven сам всё соберёт

Comment: Сделал проект на Ant - библиотека подключилась. А что вы имели ввиду под "подключением проекта к проекту", maven позволяет это сделать?

Comment: Да, maven позволяет делать модули в проекте. В отдельном каталоге у вас будет располагаться другой проект. В основной проект он будет подключаться как зависимость maven. Надеюсь, вы найдёте в поисковике как это делать. Я тут не очень силён, просто приходилось работать с проектом, где было именно так.